# Вообще не работает background-image

Tags: css

Перепробовала сто тысяч вариантов
img/bg-contacts.png
/img/bg-contacts.png
.../img/bg-contacts.png
/.../img/bg-contacts.png
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Путь выглядит следующим образом:
Рабочий стол/carpathians/img/bg-contacts.png

```css
.title-contacts {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.contacts {
  background-image: url(img/bg-contacts-2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.forms {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="contacts">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="title title-contacts">CONTACT US</h2>
    <div class="forms-contacts">
      <div class="form-contact">
        <input class="edit-contacts" type="text" name="" placeholder="NAME">
        <input class="edit-contacts" type="text" name="" placeholder="EMAIL">
        <textarea type="text-2" placeholder=""></textarea>
        <button>SUBMIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
.title-contacts {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.contacts {
  background-image: url(img/bg-contacts-2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.forms {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="contacts">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="title title-contacts">CONTACT US</h2>
    <div class="forms-contacts">
      <div class="form-contact">
        <input class="edit-contacts" type="text" name="" placeholder="NAME">
        <input class="edit-contacts" type="text" name="" placeholder="EMAIL">
        <textarea type="text-2" placeholder=""></textarea>
        <button>SUBMIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а где находиться `html`  фаил?

Comment: он в carpathians

Comment: css в отдельной папке

Comment: положите вначале картинку в папку с `css` и задайте простейший путь, чтобы добиться нужного эффекта.   после начинайте переносить выше по директории и менять путь в `css` . так вы узнаете как правильно писать путь к картинке.

Comment: У меня такая же фигёвина: при том что картинка jpg, хранится в подпапке где стоит css и html. Пробовал по разному, указывал и URL гугла, и с ординарными кавычками, и без, потом пробовал создать класс с фоновыми рисунками class="background", после чего вызвать его из css. Проделывал тоже самое что до этого - ни один способ не канает. В консоли не выдает никаких ошибок. Решил что это какая-то обнова, за которую я не по курсам.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
background-image: url(../img/bg-contacts-2.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите где лежат ваши картинки относительно css. Перепроверьте пути. Как я вижу тут в примере картинок которые вы пытаетесь поставить на background просто нет. Попробуйте указать полный путь к изображению. И вообще для ваших целей рекомендую использовать свойство `background` а не `background-image`

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: у меня разбиты html файлы по секциям
в другом файле я указывала путь img/bg.png и это работало

Comment: Если посмотреть в консоли, ошибку какую-либо выдает?

Comment: нет, ошибку не выдает

Comment: @Ingrid А вы вебсервер запускаете ?

Comment: @Ingrid единственная причина по которой не задается фоновое изображение это не видит картинку нужную страница. Прописан путь до нее не правильно! Вот [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/y0kfdg9j/1/) Обратите внимание что любая картинка из интернета по полному пути отображается

Answer (score 0):

Адрес картинки пишется относительно места файла CSS, в котором ссылаются на картинку.

К примеру: рядом с файлом `index.html` есть папка `img` (где лежит нужная картинка `bg.jpg`) и папка `CSS` (где лежит `style.css`), таким образом, из файла `style.css` при ссылке на картинку необходимо сперва подняться на папку выше, выйти из папки `CSS`, для этого набираем `"../"`, затем спускаемся в папку `img`, и уже там указываем имя файла `"../img/bg.jpg"`.

Если в адресе есть пробелы, необходимо адрес включить в кавычки.